# SwiftUI Currency Field

Tags: swift, textfield

Estoy tratando de hacer un campo precio de una manera que me parezca óptimo. Encontré el de hacking swift y varios en GitHub pero no me convencen. En cambio en la App de mi banco (N26) el que hay me gusta. Adjunto una captura. El símbolo de euro está a la izquierda del cursor, al borrar se desplaza.... no se, alguien vio algo parecido en alguna parte?, no consigo sacarlo y me esta volviendo loco. Soy consciente de que es una chorrada de pregunta pero no termino de afinarlo, pongo mi código, que me funciona bien, pero no queda como el que me gusto.

```
    @State private var precio               :  Double? = 0.0
    static let currencyFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
        let f = NumberFormatter()
        f.locale = Locale.current
        f.numberStyle = .currency
//      f.minimum = 0
//      f.maximum = 50
//      f.isLenient = true
        return f
    }()
```

```
                Section(header: Text("Precio")) {
                    HStack {
                        //Spacer()
                         
                        TextField("", value: $precio, formatter: type(of: self).currencyFormatter)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                            .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                            .keyboardType(.numbersAndPunctuation)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                            //  .font(.largeTitle)
                            .padding()
                            .background(Color.white)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        
                        
                        Image(systemName: "xmark.circle")
                            .foregroundColor(.blue)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                self.precio = 0.0
                        }
                    }
                }
```

[image: captura N26]

Comment: No he visto porque no hay ninguna imagen. Puedes agregar el código que no funciona? La App de tu banco está en lenguaje nativo?

Comment: Creo que si, ya subí la imagen y el código, disculpa, lo hice ayer desde el movil y no lo revise como debería.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

salvando que se mueva la moneda a la izquierda al borrar, y que esta sea dinámica, ya sale bien. Lo dejo por si ayuda a alguien. Ademas, será una chorrada, pero lo bien que sienta cuando lo sacas como quieres no te lo quita nadie.

```
    @State var precio = ""
    @State var moneda = "€"
    
    var formattedNumber : NSNumber {
        
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        
        guard let number = formatter.number(from: precio) else {
            print("not valid to be converted")
            return 0
        }
        
        return number
    }
    
    var formattedString : String {
        
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
        
        guard let string = formatter.string(for: self.elementoSeleccionado.precio) else {
            print("not valid to be converted")
            return "0"
        }
        
        return string
    }
    
    static let currencyFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
        let f = NumberFormatter()
        f.locale = Locale.current
        f.numberStyle = .currency
        return f
    }()

        var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView  {
            Form {

                Section(header: Text("Precio")) {
                    VStack{
                        HStack {
                            
                            TextField("Precio", text: $precio)
                                .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                                .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                                .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                                .contentShape(Rectangle())
                                .background(Color.white)
                            
                            TextField("", text: $moneda)
                                .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                                .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                                .contentShape(Rectangle())
                                .background(Color.white)
                            
                            Image(systemName: "xmark.circle")
                                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    self.precio = ""
                                }
                        }
                    }
                }

}}}
```

[image: Precio]